# javascript - retrieve current array order while in a sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In javascript, is it possible to get the state of an array at each iteration of a sort function ? Like that :

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].sort((a, b) => {
    console.log('get the current order of the array');
});
```

Or is there another approach to retrieve this information ? Maybe using a different sort function ?

Comment: Why not create your own sort function if you want to do extra steps within the actual sorting?

Comment: it depends on the user agent.

Comment: I wrote a web application called [sort-viz](https://github.com/patrickroberts/sort-viz) that does exactly this, though probably a lot more elaborate than necessary for your purposes. Feel free to check out the source code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
arr = [0, 3, 2, 4, 1]
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  console.log(arr);
  return (a - b);
})

console.log('result -->', arr);
```

Comment: That's so simple yet so clever. Thanks !

Comment: on edge, you see only empty arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz Do you know why this is the case ? Does edge implement the sort function differently from other browsers ?

Comment: some speculation: i think, all output (of the array) is suspended, because of speed.